# Moving an on-hold question to a different Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, migration, on-hold

I posted a question on a specific Stack Exchange website, and it quickly became obvious to me that it would have been more on-topic on a different Stack Exchange website. However, before I could do so, it was put "on hold". Now, the only option I'm given is to reopen the question. However, if I do that, it will quickly become closed again, as it is the wrong topic. So, how do I move a question onto a different Stack Exchange website without deleting it and asking it again entirely?

Comment: What's wrong with deleting it and reasking it on the correct site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how do I move a question onto a different Stackexchange website without deleting it and asking it again entirely?

That is the recommended way to handle this though. You can simply copy/paste the former question from the original site and post that on the other site, maybe rewriting parts to make it totally on-topic there.

The only other way to migrate the post is by flagging it for a moderator to move it. That will take more time and more effort from both of you, so that seems useless to me.